# Can you have express middleware check a route-specific config?

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I have a node/express project in which for any *POST* request made, I want to validate the fields in the body of the request.

For this I would like to setup a config per route that handles *POST* methods, the config would have a list of fields with their constraints, something like this:

```
router.post('/some_path', function(request, response, next){
    this.fieldsToValidate = [
        {
            name: 'field_name',
            required: true,
            ...
        },
        ...
    ]
    // handle route after validation
}
```

I would like this to be a per-route configuration, such that I can define a set of fields and their constraints and they will be validated by middleware automatically.

so middleware would look something like:

```
function(request, response, next){
    if (request.method === 'POST'){
        this.fieldsToValidate.forEach(function(field){
            //do some validation
        });
    }
    next();
}
```

I understand that middleware is run before the request, but is there any way to have a per-route configuration like this and validate it with middleware?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think, it will be good practice if you can validate all your fields in model or if you are using mongoose for mongodb, you can use mongoose middleware like pre to validate your fields.

Comment: @rroxysam could you add that as an answer and give a pseudo code example?

Comment: If you still have a need , i can post.

Answer (score 2):

How about this one:
use express-validator([check in detail](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator)) and route regex to check your parameters，assume that your apis are all in */api/* *:

**the server:**

```
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(expressValidator());
app.use('/api',function(req,res,next){
    switch(req.baseUrl)
    {
        case ://API 1
          req.checkHeaders('user','valid header').notEmpty();
          break;
        case ://API 2
        //Others
    }
    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if (errors) {
        res.send('There have been validation errors: ' + util.inspect(errors), 400);
        return;
    }
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[express-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validator) an express.js middleware for [node-validator](https://github.com/chriso/validator.js). I'm using on my projects working good. You can do both validation and sanitization.

```
  // VALIDATION
  // checkBody only checks req.body; none of the other req parameters
  // Similarly checkParams only checks in req.params (URL params) and
  // checkQuery only checks req.query (GET params).
  req.checkBody('postparam', 'Invalid postparam').notEmpty().isInt();
  req.checkParams('urlparam', 'Invalid urlparam').isAlpha();
  req.checkQuery('getparam', 'Invalid getparam').isInt();

  // OR assert can be used to check on all 3 types of params.
  // req.assert('postparam', 'Invalid postparam').notEmpty().isInt();
  // req.assert('urlparam', 'Invalid urlparam').isAlpha();
  // req.assert('getparam', 'Invalid getparam').isInt();

  // SANITIZATION
  // as with validation these will only validate the corresponding
  // request object
  req.sanitizeBody('postparam').toBoolean();
  req.sanitizeParams('urlparam').toBoolean();
  req.sanitizeQuery('getparam').toBoolean();
```